# Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver with Gradle and Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, gradle, spring-boot

My problem is the following. I'm learning how to use JDBC, Gradle and Spring framework (I'm new to those subjects). I've been trying to implement the following [example](http://xantorohara.blogspot.ca/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-sample.html) with one difference, MySQL database instead of PostgreSQL.

Like I specified in the title, my application ends with following error `Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` (stack trace at the end of the post).

Of course I've been googling and reading before posting this question and I found that `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` should be loaded either using loader in program or it also can be done withing Gradle build script.

My questions are the following:

1. Why authors example works without loader (either in program either in build script)
2. If loader is absolutely necessarily, could you explain briefly how to implement it?

### My modified `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" } 
    } 
    dependencies { 
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:0.5.0.M6") 
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'  
    } 
} 

apply plugin: "java" 
apply plugin: "spring-boot" 

buildDir = "out" 

jar { 
    baseName = "sb-jdbc" 
    version = "0.1" 
} 

repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" } 
} 

dependencies { 
    def springBootVersion = '1.0.0.RC1'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springBootVersion")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.11")
}
```

### My `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/:3306/******
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=******

# Specify the DBMS
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate settings are prefixed with spring.jpa.hibernate.*
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

### Stack trace (not full):

```
2015-01-03 20:09:20.203  WARN 10298 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate demo.UserRepository.jdbc; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at demo.WebBindGradleApplication.main(WebBindGradleApplication.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate demo.UserRepository.jdbc; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:530)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:530)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 59 common frames omitted

2015-01-03 20:09:20.254  INFO 10298 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2015-01-03 20:09:20.308  INFO 10298 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-jdbc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/snakeyaml-1.14.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/classmate-1.0.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-expression-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-juli-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar!/, jar:file:/home/pucek/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/WebBindGradle/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar!/]
2015-01-03 20:09:20.308  INFO 10298 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2015-01-03 20:09:20.310 ERROR 10298 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

Thank you in advance for any advices, exploanations, shared examples et cetera!
Cheers!

### Edit #1

As Mr. Kamoor kindly suggested it may be problem of lack of local *jar file. I suspected that Gradle will download it automatically from repository, in case if it wouldn't I added it manually (I work on STS). Here we can see that mysql-connector-java jar is there.

[image: We can see Driver class for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
[image: And here we can see that the mysql-connector-java jar is added]

I'm sorry for those screen shoots, I just don't know other way to show that I added it (I'm not used to Eclipse).

Comment: Do you want to update to new version of spring boot 1.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: Just tried with `'1.2.0.RC1'` and got same result. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: RC1 is not a GA release. Use RELEASE. And use that version for the Spring Boot plugin (why do you have 0.5.0.x?). Also I don't see why you need mysql as a build classpath dependency, so that looks odd.

Comment: You don't have to specify the driver as with a JDBC4 driver it will automatically be registered so no need to load it yourself. Old that old loading and reading with `Class.forName` is pre JDBC and should be avoided nowadays.

Comment: Thank you for quick feedback. @DaveSyer, I use old version of Spring Boot Plugin simply because newer version fails to build (I've been looking at numerous examples on web and this is only one that build successfully).

I will try to build it with newest Spring Boot plugin.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for making it clear, I'm so tired of lack of clear information about J2EE projects.

Comment: @DaveSyer, I manage to build it with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.0.RELEASE` and also set `def springBootVersion = '1.2.0.RELEASE'`. Unfortunately application fails with same error, `Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you remove mysql from the build dependencies?

Comment: Does it work on the command line?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to comment lines with classpath and compilation for mysql, it succeed to build the project but didn't manage to execute it because of same error.

Could you precise what you mean by `Does it work on the command line?`?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm struggling with this right now.

Comment: Make sure there is not "extra character" in the driver reference. You may want to trim() the value after you read the "spring.datasource.driver-class-name".

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by trial and error. What did it for me was to remove a driver reference form application.properties file. So my application.properties file looks like this, and the error immediately went away:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username = root 
spring.datasource.password = fake
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
mybatis.config=mybatis-config.xml
mybatis.check-config-location=true
```

I think it has to do with the probability that you need that driver in the embedded Tomcat and not in the application code itself

Comment: Just for next readers, I was having similar problem and was caused by gradle failing when downloading mysql jar. Was using 2.11, changed to 2.14.1 and gradle downloaded the jar.

Comment: Nothing to do with gradle or maven, I face the same issue, and the solution is same as what you did. remove the driver reference, instantiate Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") in code.

Comment: The driver is for another vendor. You cannot use both drivers at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I know my case is special, but I should let others know what I have found.

In my case,
- I had installed gradle with brew, gradle version is **2.1** (even now)
- Problem: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found

I tried many ways but finally I solved the problem: Upgrade Gradle (3.3, for example.)

- upgrade gradle
- gradle init again (remove build.gradle and settings.gradle)
- make copy everything from old build/settings to new build/settings

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

@EnableAutoConfiguration will make sure appropriate beans are loaded, here driver will be loaded by Spring boot. See [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html)

In your case, I do not see MySQL driver jar file is not included in the class path and hence Spring is unable to find the Driver class. Search for "ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener" in the log to see all the jars are included to run the application.

Comment: I thought Gradle will download it just like it downloads Spring dependencies. Unfortunately `ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener` is not present in logs generated with Gradle. Thank you very much for quick feedback! :)

Comment: It is on the classpath (build.gradle) and looks like it is in the repository so are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: I added it manually using STS, also updated my post with screenshot, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue..

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.27</version>
</dependency>
```

then check application.properties

Comment: He is using Gradle, what POM.xml?